# The Scite open filter is not working properly, how do I get the open dialog drop down menu showing filters?

Tags: scintilla, scite

In Scite text editor there is a global properties file shipped with the editor. I downloaded Scite latest version from the website but when I open the open dialog in scite, not all the filters show up in the drop down menu. For example, verilog, TeX, and many more filters do not show up, even though they are enabled in the sciteglobal.properties file under open.filter

Is this a bug in scite or am I missing something?

For example some filters that do work are perl, lua, ada - but tex, verilog, pascal, and more do not show up in the drop down.  They are not commented out in the global properties file.

A temporary work around is to move them around to different spots in the global properties file. for example if I move them to non alphabetical order and put them at the very top, they seem to be enabled.

I know the ALL SOURCE files filter is limited to 256 characters or something similar, but the individual filters should not be limited in the drop down menu and they should not be missing.. right?

I compiled scite from the source code myself, and it has the same problem. Or is there something as designed that I am missing and this is not a bug?

Comment: [SciTE mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/scite-interest).

Comment: reported bug to the sourceforge, found a solution to the problem. see answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to my own question...

The default sciteglobal.properties file that ships with scite is incorrect. It is parsed wrong due to the commenting out of items such as modula open filter.  Remove all pound signs in the open filters so nothing is commented out in the open filter list, and this fixes the problem.

Instead of commenting out the items in open.filter list, use imports.exclude to remove an item from being seen.